# Update view using variable

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

Im attempting to update a view in another classes using a variabes but for some strange reason i get a `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. The function works when called from the page where the view exist but not anywhere else. Is there something i'm doing wrong?

```
     func updateView(trackName: String, image: UIImage){
    let view = IntroController()
    view.cardLabel.text = trackName
    view.cardImage.image = image
}




 func startProcess(completionHandler: (Bool) -> ()) -> (){
            getUserData{
                msg in
                if (msg){
                    print("STEP 1: Get User Data Complete")
                    self.getSearchTerms{
                        termRtn in
                        if (termRtn){
                            print("STEP 2: Get Search Terms Complete")
                            self.searchTerms = self.createArray()
                            self.search{
                                msg in
                                if (msg){
                                    print("STEP 3: Search Completed!")
                                    print(parResults.count)
                                    self.downloadImages{ dlComplete in
                                        if (dlComplete){

                                            print("STEP 4: CardImage has been downloaded or created")
                     updateView(trackName: "test1", image: UIImage(named: "test");
                                            completionHandler(true)
                                        }
                                    }

                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: is the `cardLabel` initialized correctly at this point?

Comment: So where do you actually invoke the `updateView` method when it fails?

Comment: A lot more of your code is needed to answer your question.

Comment: @FelixSFD is it has been

Comment: @Snusmumrikken within a function placed in `viewDidload()`

Comment: Do you understand that `let view = IntroController()` creates a new object rather than giving you a reference to an existing `IntroController` that may have been initialized elsewhere?

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi Its quite cluttered and quite irrelevant to the question thats why it was truncated. updated Code

Comment: @PhillipMills i wasn't aware of that, how can i create a reference object instead?

Comment: That depends on how/where you created the first `IntroController` that you need a reference to .

Comment: Hardly irrelevant since not enough of it is there to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Since you provided not much code I will still make an attempt to answer. The `IntroController` you instantiate probably does not have any code in its constructor that loads the actual XiB. So you are trying to reference the view property of the `IntroController`, that has not loaded its view. Post the content of `IntroController` if you need more help.